# Check case of characters in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have two options in HTML select input with values as

```
AbhiNAV5
RaviNATH6
```

User selects one of these values and that will be stored in DB. 
If any user directly changes the value in DB as `ABHINAV5 or abhinav5` or `RAVINATH6 or ravinath6` (or possibly however he want in any case),
then I am not able to show the value in dropdown. Instead it adds a blank entry

Here is HTML

```
    <select id="Select1" clientidmode="Static" class="htmlDropdown" runat="server" data-ng-disabled="!PropCollection.IsConfigured" data-ng-model="PropCollection.ViewerName" style="width: 150px;" tabindex="2">
        <option value="AbhiNAV5">AbhiNAV5</option>
        <option value="RaviNATH6">RaviNATH6</option>
    </select>
```

Is there any way to handle the case? I want it to be case insensitive.

Any help appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply change the model to lowercase and the values of the options to lowercase so they match-up when they're bound. Think that's the simplest solution.

Comment: @Lokesh happy to help